# Pentaho DI: map stream of formulas to a stream of values. Is a lookup possible?

Tags: formula, pentaho, lookup, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I have a stream from a DB table, that contains rules (formulas) that I'd like to map it to a stream with data accordingly to the Name column value. Let's say like this (rules are just dummy examples, not part of the question):

```
Data:
---------------
Name    | Sales
---------------
Food    | 1000
Alkohol | 1000
Gas     | 1000

Rules:
---------------
Name    | Rule
---------------
Food    | [if Sales > 100 then 0.5 else 0.7]
Alkohol | [if Sales > 25 then 1 else 2]
Gas     | [if Sales > 500 then 0.7 else 0.5]
```

Is there a flow possible, that allows to lookup for a rule using Name column, and then apply the matching rule to the row?

Currently I have a user defined java class, that iterates over array of rules for each row of data, applying a matching rule as formula:

```
        Formula formula = new Formula(rules[i]);
        context.setRowData(row);
        formula.initialize(context);
```

... but it is not very efficient. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with **Modified Javascript** step and using **eval(Rule)** ?

Comment: Don't think it makes big difference to java class making the same. Have to look what works faster.
I was wondering if it is possible to apply a formula from a stream with a standard pentaho step.

While you gave me an idea make a lookup before evaluation. Thank you! It is already an improvement.